# Build cmake library without RPATH (use executable_path instead)

Tags: c++, macos, cmake

I am using CMake to build a library. Here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
project(simpleLibrary)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
add_library(simpleLibrary SHARED main.cpp)
```

It is very simple and clear. It builds a library in cmake-build-debug. I use otool to check shared library id:

```
➜  cmake-build-debug git:(master) ✗ otool -L libsimpleLibrary.dylib
libsimpleLibrary.dylib:
        @rpath/libsimpleLibrary.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
        /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 904.4.0)
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1292.60.1)
➜  cmake-build-debug git:(master) ✗
```

It builds with @rpath by default. In my case I need to use @executable_path because I am facing linkage problems in the Mac OS without Xcode installed. Is there a way to change it in CMake build? I could change it using install_name_tool but I have to make that on build stage. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I am facing linkage problems in the Mac OS without Xcode installed." - What kind of problems have you faced? Note, that **build** artifacts are not intended to be copied into other directories or into other machine. For that you need to **install** your library. When install, CMake gives you full control over RPATH setting. For more info see [CMake RPATH handling](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/doc/cmake/RPATH-handling) wiki.

Comment: I am facing dyld: Library not loaded, Reason: image not found. After using @executable_path everything works.